# What is "plugin authoring"?

Tags: jquery-plugins, plugins, naming-conventions, naming, conventions

First time I see **plug-in authoring** term in jQuery docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

What is "plugin authoring"? How is it different from *"plug-in development"*, *"plug-in tutorial"*, *"plug-in architecture"*?

In http://docs.jquery.com/Talk:Plugins/Authoring written:

*It might be better to rename this page as 'Plugin Development' or use another common dev-word instead of 'Authoring'. I feel the same about the navigation. 'Authoring' is a creative alternative, but not really preferred. Am I the only one?*

*I would tend to agree*

*Yes, I would agree that "Plugin Development" might be a better alternative to "Authoring." Do you think it's causing some confusion right now? That would be the biggest reason for change, in my opinion.*

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/authoring

Comment: Thanks, I read **foldoc** dictionary article first, which mostly same as in wiki: *process of creating the content of a document* +1